# How to get the data from Tektronix Oscilloscope from a certain peak and then probe it until a certain amount of points with Python

Tags: python

I know how to get the plot and save data from the Tektronix oscilloscope with Python. I have some peaks and then they decay (periodic dampings). I want to write a code to capture a peak and go through 2000 points (the end of damping, see the plot) and save the data (because I want to get the damping factor).

I know how to get the peaks by `detect_peaks` by this:

```
ind = detect_peaks(Volts, mph:1.4, show=True)
print(ind)
```

When I `print(ind)`, it prints time which voltages are peaks, but not voltages. I have a problem because if I use a `while` loop I can count time from one peak to 2000 points after, but I do not know how can I do it in a way that automatically gives me both Time and Volts.

[image]

Here is the summary:

I want to get one of the peaks and acquire all the voltages until the end of damped oscillation.

here is my code:

```
import visa
import numpy as np
from struct import unpack
import pylab
from detecta import detect_peaks

#how to get the plot from Tektronix
# Establish Connection
rm = visa.ResourceManager('@py') # Calling PyVisaPy library
#scope = rm.open_resource('USB0::0x0699::0x0409::C010730::INSTR') # Connecting via USB
scope = rm.open_resource('USB0::1689::883::C011533::0::INSTR') # Connecting via LAN 
 
# Setting source as Channel 1
scope.write('DATA:SOU CH2') 
scope.write('DATA:WIDTH 1') 
scope.write('DATA:ENC RPB')

# Getting axis info
ymult = float(scope.query('WFMPRE:YMULT?')) # y-axis least count
yzero = float(scope.query('WFMPRE:YZERO?')) # y-axis zero error
yoff = float(scope.query('WFMPRE:YOFF?')) # y-axis offset
xincr = float(scope.query('WFMPRE:XINCR?')) # x-axis least count

# Reading Binary Data from instrument
scope.write('CURVE?')
data = scope.read_raw() # Reading binary data
headerlen = 2 + int(data[1]) # Finding header length
header = data[:headerlen] # Separating header 
ADC_wave = data[headerlen:-1] # Separating data

# Converting to Binary to ASCII
ADC_wave = np.array(unpack('%sB' % len(ADC_wave),ADC_wave))

Volts = (ADC_wave- yoff ) * ymult + yzero
Time = np.arange(0, xincr * len(Volts), xincr)

#getting  peaks
ind = detect_peaks(Volts, mph=1.4, show=True)
print(ind)

#attempt for taking 2000 piint after the first peak
a2=ind[0] #first peak 
i=ind[0]
while i<a2+20:
    print(i)
    i+=1


#Plotting Volt Vs. Time
pylab.plot(Time, Volts) 
pylab.show()
```

Comment: Where does the `detect_peaks` function come from?

Comment: @mkrieger1 from `detecta`

Comment: If you have your data in lists, for example, you can take the time points at which the voltage is max (returned by the `detect_peaks` function), determine their index (at the time list) and use these indeces to get their corresponding voltage value (from the voltage list). To get all 2000 points after each you can use a `for` loop and list slicing (`[i:2000+i]`where i is the index for one of the peaks)

Comment: @RamónMárquez I cannot understand properly. I have Volts (my voltages) and Time (which is a range). for example, I plot them like `pylab.plot(Time, Volts)`. And if I want to save my data, which I do not want to save anything, I will use `np.stack`.  For your approach, my problem exactly is that I cannot get the volts corresponding to the time. I have the time at which Volts are peaks but my problem is that I cannot get the corresponding voltages with this `detect_peaks`.

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this? What library are you using, for example?

Comment: @AMC I edited my question and added the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Volts` is a numpy array. When you call `detect_peaks` on your `Volts` array, it should return the data points (aka the indices, not the time values as I mistakenly suggested in my comment), then you can say:

```
ind = detect_peaks(Volts, mph:1.4, show=True)
voltage_damping_intervals = np.array([Volts[i:i+2000] for i in ind])
```

And just choose which interval to print by picking its corresponding peak, for example:

```
print(voltage_damping_intervals[1])
# prints 2000 data points after the second peak
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot! I did the same for Time, and the get the first peak, and then transform it into a column by `reshape`, and then I plotted it. Also, I wanted to use it for getting a damping factor, that is why I needed column data rather than array ones.